# How to dynamically create a link from SQL results

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to dynamically create a link from my SQL query output, but I am not sure how to uniquely get the values of the result that has been clicked. I used an anchor to call a method in my controller, but I don't know how to recognise what has been clicked.

Heres my view code where I send data from the controller and output it:

```
 <?php
        if (isset($q)) {
            foreach ($q as $row) {
                ?><a href="/CI/index.php/mainController/title"><?php echo $row->title; ?> </a><?php
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Heres the method I call, and how I try to get the data using CIs built in methods but as it is not a form it doesn't work and I am not sure what else I can use to get the value:

```
public function title(){
        $id = $this->input->get('title');
        print_r($id . "hello");
    }
```

So I would like to know what is the best way to get a specific value from output of an SQL statement without having to use a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [pass values to your controller with the URI](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri)

```
public function title($id){
    // $id = $this->input->get('title');
    print_r($id . "hello");
}
```

and to link to the controller

```
echo '<a href="'.site_url('mainController/title/'.$row->title).'">';
```

Note you should use the [URL helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) to use the `site_url()` function.

I suggest you [read the manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/) to learn about more of the tools that are made available to you from CodeIgniter's core, or else you're not really taking advantage of a framework.

Answer (score 2):

You could append some sort of identifier in the url

i.e.

```
<a href="/path/to/controller.php?something=else">Click!</a>
```

Then the controller.php, you can retrieve the variable

```
$something = $_REQUEST['something']; //$something = 'else'
```

Comment: This is one way to do it, but doesn't take advantage of [URI segments](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri) or the `site_url()` function which are both built-in features of CodeIgniter

Comment: Sorry a little confused how can I make the `something=else` from my results. From what I gather I want mine to be like this `<a href="/CI/index.php/mainController/title?title="><?php echo $row->title; ?> </a>` but how can i get the value of the title in the URL?

Comment: echo it before closing the tag

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an id to the A tag and then read the value of the A tag in jQuery/javascript when the page loads.